# Exporting data from the Ignite cache

Tags: ignite

I see multiple examples of loading and processing data with Apache Ignite. But how do I export data from the ignite cache after it’s been processed?

I'm looking forward to implement processing of some large CSV files on a cluster. Say it’s a simple transformation that preprocesses data in a specific column. After I’m finished w it, how do I get it off the cache to an S3 bucket or some other location. My data will be partitioned across the nodes for speed of loading and loaded as a KV cache.

Is there a standard mechanism to export data from a cache (CSV in / CSV out) ? I've found that ML models can leverage the Exporter APIs. But that's not my use case.

Are scan queries a standard way to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to export the entire data set, then yes,

[ScanQuery](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/key-value-api/using-scan-queries) in combination with [AffinityRun](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/distributed-computing/collocated-computations#colocating-by-partition) for every partition is probably the most efficient way to iterate over all cache entries and export them.

With `affinityRun` we ask every node to export its part of data, instead of pulling the data to a single node for export.

Answer (score 1):

`sqlline` utility comes with Apache Ignite and it can also write CSV files with `!outputFormat csv`.